# Radius of convergence of fredholm IE

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am reading Fredholm integral equation.
The equation is
$$ y(x)=f(x)+ \lambda\int_{a}^b\int_{a}^bk(x,s)y(s)ds$$ and the theory say that the solution is possible only when $\lambda< B^{-1}$ where $B= \left(\int\int |k(x,s)|^2dxds\right)^{1/2}$.

For a certain problem where $k(x,s)=e^{x-s}$ with $a=0,b=1$. I calculate this bound and I get this equal to $0.85$. However, when I calculate the solution in terms of the Resolvent Kernel, I get the condition that $\lambda<1$ which is a relaxed condition from the above.
Can somebody tell what is the point that I am missing?

Comment: As you formulate, there can be no solution when $λ\ge B^{-1}$. What I would expect from such fixed-point equations is that solutions are guaranteed to exist if $λ< B^{-1}$, with no claim to the opposite case. Please carefully check your source again what the actual formulation is.

Comment: I wanted to know is this condition $\lambda<B^{-1}$ a necessary condition for the solution to exist or is it just sufficient? From looking at the example, I think it is just sufficient

Comment: The Banach fixed-point theorem gives you a unique solution as long as the Lipschitz constant, here $|λ|B$, is smaller than $1$. With a bit more work one can show the same for the inverse operator as a bounded operator. In matrix terms, $B$ looks like the Frobenius norm. It is well-known that other norms give sharper bounds, this might also translate to the integral operator.